# How can I get the column names from a select statement in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I access the column name of the field value inside the for loop.

I don't want to have to hard code the column names.

```
DataAccessObject NewDao = Settings.IntranetDBDataAccessObject;
string UserName = "";
string WorkPhone = "";
string ColumnName = "";

if (Request.QueryString["user_id"] != null && Request.QueryString["user_id"].Length != 0) {
     SqlCommand Select = new SqlCommand("SELECT emp_name, phone_work FROM employees WHERE emp_id="+ 
     NewDao.ToSql(Request.QueryString["user_id"].ToString(),FieldType.Integer),NewDao);

    DataRowCollection newDr = Select.Execute().Tables[0].Rows;

    for(int i = 0; i < newDr.Count; i++) {
       UserName = newDr[i]["emp_name"].ToString();
       WorkPhone = newDr[i]["phone_work"].ToString();

       //Is there a way to access the Key column that contains data row field value?
      //ColumnName = newDr[i][ ?columnNameFromSelect? ].ToString();
    }

    // Show a label value 
    UserInfo.Text =  UserName + ", phone: "+WorkPhone;
}
```

Comment: See the docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why? Performing any kind of lookup is going to add time to any execution. Is it really an issue to have the column names in a constant?

Comment: Yes I dont want to do have to do an application change or update in the future. I want the app code to read * from its select and basically return the column name associated return values from that type of query.   Im making a JSON output from this and when a new column gets added to the table in the future, again we wont need to update the c#.  I had been able to do this in PHP pretty easily several projects ago...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DataTable`'s `Columns` property:

```
DataTable table = Select.Execute().Tables[0];
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        string colName = col.ColumnName;
        object value = row[col];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What if any imports will I need to use "DataTable" ?

Comment: @ede79b3fbf673a9a8e9bf3db02aeb7: sorry, don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the schema from your query also from the datareader :

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

as per documentation from msdn :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
section about Getting Schema Information from the DataReader

Comment: Yes Ive been able to get the table schema a couple ways to return the columns in other test scripts, but looping on the table column names and nesting or in parallel looping on the select statement with rows does not return the output that I want. Im ultimately using this script to create a json data output and am using this script as an example.  I recall this being easy in PHP and MYSQL on a past project.

Comment: Then please rephrase your question because it is not clear to me what you really want.

Comment: I guess a fair example of what I want is documented in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php

Comment: From high level point of view there is almost no difference between the getschematable api and the one i found in your link for php. And in the example provided there is also a loop.

Comment: Im not sure I agree/ they are looping on a standard table level sql result statement.  and thus thanks to the method supplied, are able to get column name in line.  the only examples Ive seen you describe are going directly a tier up and querying the table for its column arrays... i am able to do this... but what I cannot connect is the two very different arrays when doing this with C# and the approach I have been told in some examples above.  The example link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php that I supplied shows much more metadata accessible to a row select statement.

Comment: It is not language specific at all. I am sure underneath the same mechanism are being used, both for c# and php. Eventually the driver needs to be consulted for the metadata. You asked for the columns names only and this I provided along with the other answers that are equally good. I am sure you are not satisfied, but then I still fail to see what you want. For sure not only columnnames.

Comment: if its not lang specific then can you provide a code example?

Comment: I meant that eventually the way it is implemented in the api provided for those specific languages is going to call the same low level drivers that have a set of api functions that is well defined. The same low level api functions will be called whether you are programming in php or in c#. I am only trying to help here, I didn't mean to argue about this.

Comment: Hi Phill, I have looked around and would be very happy to see an example of doing this "meta query" that boils down to essentially saying select * from a table but being able to return the columnName and Value from the select makes it so any new columns added to the tables do not require a code update on the application side as new columns are introduced.

Comment: I basically and using the return data as the Key/Value of a JSON output service etc.